# link not working with firefox using angular-ui

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have issues with firefox using some links. I have a webpage which i am using angular-ui routing. In some pages where i post the files the links only work in Chrome (it opens the document - which is what i want) and in Firefox it does not.

```
 <div class="list-group">
      <button ng-repeat="file in hcl16" type="button" class="list-group-item"><a href="documente/HCL/2016/{{file}}">{{file}}</a></button>
 </div>
```

The files are shown but link does not open in firefox.

Has anyone any idea why?

Comment: Angular has a special directive for links using data from scope/ctrl: `ng-href` have you tried using that?

Comment: yes, but stil not working with firefox

Comment: Could you provide a fiddle or similar where this can be demonstrated?

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try below code- 
I think you are missing #/ -> href="#/documente/HCL/2016/{{file}}"
        OR 
if you are using  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
then use href="/documente/HCL/2016/{{file}}"

```
<div class="list-group">
  <button ng-repeat="file in hcl16" type="button" class="list-group-item"><a href="#/documente/HCL/2016/{{file}}">{{file}}</a></button>
```

Comment: Please provide a plunker link for same.

Answer (score 0):

I use this

```
<a ng-repeat="file in hcl16" href="documente/HCL/2016/{{file}}" class="list-group-item list-group-item-text">{{file}}</a>
```

instead of this

```
<button ng-repeat="file in hcl16" type="button" class="list-group-item"><a href="documente/HCL/2016/{{file}}">{{file}}</a></button>
```

and now works in both Chrome and firefox